# Drawing a rectangle on a chart

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I wrote the Code below to draw a rectangle and fill it on a chart but I only get the chart as result in the end without the rectangle. Any idea? Thank you

Public Class Form1

```
Dim myBrush As Brush

Public Sub Chart1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Chart1.Click


    Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(0, 1)
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(1, 2)
    Chart1.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
    Chart1.Series(0).Color = Color.Black


End Sub

Private Sub PostPaint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs) Handles Chart1.PostPaint
    myBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Coral)
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
    Chart1.CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, rect)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Visual Studio is an editor..what language are you using? What graphics language are you using? Put those in the tags. Visual-Studio implies you are creating add-ins in visual studio.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, in fact, I am using Visual Basic

Comment: Never using CreateGraphics.  Use the Graphic object supplied by the event: `e.Graphics`.  Dispose your brush, too.

Comment: @LarsTech Can you please correct my code in order to create a rectangle on my chart?? Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you try to research it?  `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, rect)`  `myBrush.Dispose()`